# Storing \n as text not a newline in a linux file?

Tags: node.js, linux, ascii, newline

I want to store \n as text in a Linux file so that when I retrieve the file I get the following:

```
Hello\nWorld
```

instead of

```
Hello
World
```

I want to store \n as text and so that it does not represent a new line character. So I need to write the file so it interprets \n as text and not a newline.

I have tried \n but this still resulted in a new line.

I am writing the file using the printf linux command. It appends text to a Linux file.

Example: I currently do not have a file called file.txt

```
printf "text goes here" >> file.txt
printf " more text now" >> file.txt
```

Now I will have a file called file.txt with the text `text goes here more text now`

I have included the ascii tag but feel free to remove that tag if you do not think it is applicable because I was not sure..

Comment: It must be possible because using nano I can put \n as text and not a new line. I now need to do it programmatcally.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'hello\\nworld' > /tmp/1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Backslash the backslash in printf

```
printf 'Hello\\nWorld' > file.txt
```

Or use `'\n'` as a second parameter that fills a template:

```
printf 'Hello%sWorld' '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash `\` is an escape character and will be interpreted together with the following character. The text `\n` is interpreted and replaced by a single character (Line Feed - LF).

To achieve what you want, escape the backslash with another one. So `\\` is interpreted and replaced by a single `\` and the following `n` character is not touched.